# Do I need an HTTP server (e.g. Express, Nginx, etc.) for react app on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, http, heroku, routes

I am little novice when it comes to deploying full-stack applications.

I am building a basic react app (created with `create-react-app`) that needs to deployed on Heroku and hit my Rails backend API (separate repo, already built and deployed on Heroku). Do I need to setup a http server (i.e. Express or Nginx) to route requests from the browser to the backend app? Or can I just rely on the default webpack production server to handle this.

Appreciate anyone's help!!

Comment: Just use create-react-app buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack . Note the `static.json` file needed

Comment: or just deploy it for free on netlify

Comment: if its a basic app, just use a package like `axios` to make http requests directly to your backend, it'll work as well on your heroku server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a back-end to serve static content on Heroku.

Have a look at this article to get started: https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration

It uses https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack and it's easy to get stated, I managed to deploy the example app in a few minutes.